# Wish for Better c++ Stack Implementation using Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stack

I am using Microsoft VS 2013 on Windows 7 64-bit

I found the following simple Stack implementation on TutorialsPoint

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm

Though this was just a simple example, I wanted whatever was "popped" be returned to the caller.  As it is now, you have to access top() and then pop() the top for the functionality that I want.

I tried to change "void pop()" to "T pop()" and then modify the return type of pop() in the implementation, but the compiler balked about not being able to convert string types.

First, shouldn't a better implementation return the value "popped"

and, if so,

How do I modify the code so that I return was it "popped" ?

If not clear, I would like to use:

```
        cout << stringStack.pop() << std::endl;
```

instead of the two lines needed below.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <string> 
#include <stdexcept> 

using namespace std; 

template <class T> 
class Stack 
{ 
private: 
    vector<T> elems;                // elements 

public: 
    void push( T const& );      // push element 
    void pop();         // pop element 
    T top() const;          // return top element 
    bool empty() const      // return true if empty. 
    { 
        return elems.empty(); 
    } 
}; 

template <class T> 
void Stack<T>::push (T const& elem) 
{ 
    // append copy of passed element 
    elems.push_back(elem); 
} 

template <class T> 
void Stack<T>::pop () 
{ 
    if (elems.empty()) 
    { 
        throw out_of_range( "Stack<>::pop(): empty stack" ); 
} 

// remove last element 
elems.pop_back(); 

} 

template <class T> 
T Stack<T>::top () const 
{ 
    if (elems.empty()) 
    { 
        throw out_of_range( "Stack<>::top(): empty stack" ); 
    } 

    // return copy of last element 
    return elems.back(); 

} 

int main() 
{ 
    try 
            { 
        Stack<int>      intStack;   // stack of ints 
        Stack<string>   stringStack;    // stack of strings 

        // manipulate int stack 
        intStack.push( 7 ); 
        cout << intStack.top() <<endl; 

        // manipulate string stack 
        stringStack.push( "hello" ); 
        stringStack.push( "world" ); 
        cout << stringStack.top() << std::endl; 
        stringStack.pop(); 
        cout << stringStack.top() << std::endl; 
        stringStack.pop(); 
        cout << stringStack.top() << std::endl; 

        return 0;

    } 
    catch ( exception const& ex ) 
    { 
        cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() <<endl; 
        return -1; 

    } 

}
```

Comment: What compiler error did you get about strings and regardling which line?

Comment: There is a good reason why `pop()` does not return a value. You may want to do some research on the topic rather than trying to reinvent the wheel in your image.

Answer (score 4):

BTW there is a [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)

You are asking for "better" code to save you a line of code as the other answers suggest e.g.

```
template <class T> 
T Stack<T>::pop () 
{ 
    T ret = elems.top():
    elems.pop_back(); 
    return ret;
}
```

This may copy the element more which might not be safe in the presence of exceptions - e.g. out of memory.

There is a detailed [guru of the week](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/008.htm) about this. Having `top` and `pop` separate make it easier to keep the container in a consistent state in the presence of exceptions.

Comment: TY, doctorlove, I am much wiser for your help on this.  I would not have guessed this.

Answer (score 1):

[std::vector::pop_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) doesn't return the element, it just removes it from the container

You need:

```
T back = elems.back();
elemes.pop_back();
return back;
```

Comment: @RajACS the ideea is to understand the problem and the solution, not to find working code snippets. You are welcome.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I am returning to c++ after many years of web development.  I am just trying to re-learn (some things) in the context of "new conveniences".  Reading the comments from (at least) doctorlove (above) I have already learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

```
T pop()
{
    const T popped = top();
    // original code of pop goes here.
    return popped
}
```

As to your question

> shouldn't a better implementation return the value "popped"

In general, returning an object can cause copying, which can throw an exception, at it might require additional resources. This is dangerous - you could get a system that is resource strapped, and so you want to free things by popping stuff (for example). The problem is - you can't, it'll just require more resources.

Comment: Ok, great.  Your solution works.  TY. So, my next question, which might help me clarify what 'const' keyword is doing in 2 different places: (1) Is the 'const' in your "const T popper = top();" code needed so that a "copy" is not created?  and (2) when I tried to add 'const' after the pop() public declaration -- so, "T pop()const" -- very similar to the top() method -- I get errors about "'cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'" AND "Conversion loses qualifiers" -- so -- why do I need the 'const' after top() but not after your new pop() ??

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for this. This site doesn't work well for dialogues. There's no pace even to put code snippets in these comments.